# how to open inspect element (f12) from selenium by code?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, web-inspector

i want to check the network tab in inspect/developer tool,want to open that screen directly from my code in selenium webdriver in java.
or simply how can i press F12 button by my script

Answer (score 0):

Opening dev tools is pretty simple:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
***
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
```

But it will open the last tab opened.
Since Selenium uses a new temporary browser profile you will need:

1. run Chrome manualy
2. open dev tools and Network tab
3. run Chrome in that profile, which had opened the Network tab

You can dedicate a browser profile for your tests to achieve opening Network tab in every run.